# JavaScript. Логика работы двойного условного (тернарного) оператора "?"

Tags: javascript, условия

Простая задача:

- если A и B   `true`   -> показать "A и B"
- если A или B `true`   -> показать "A или B"
- если A и B   `false`  -> показать "NONE"

Код:

```
let a = false;
let b = true;

document.write(a ? b ? "A и B" : "A или B" : "NONE");
```

Проблема:

Если `a == true` и `b == false`, то показывает "A или B".
Но если `a == false`, `b == true`, то показывает "NONE" - Почему не "A или B?

Я ожидал, что если любая одна из этих переменных будет `false`,
то отобразится вариант "A или B".

Объясните логику при использовании двойного условного оператора.
Нигде в справочниках не могу найти.
Может кто ссылочку подкинет, где почитать.

Эта форма записи была обнаружена у учителя в лекции, но без объяснения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Данное выражение

```
a ? b ? "A и B" : "A или B" : "NONE"
```

разбирается следующим образом:

```
a ? (b ? "A и B" : "A или B") : "NONE"
```

Отсюда видно, что если `a` -> `false`, то выполняется вторая ветка, в которой есть только `none`.

В качестве решения можно добавить проверку `b` в эту ветвь:

```
a ? (b ? "A и B" : "A или B") : (b ? "A или B" : "NONE")
```

Либо изменить проверяемые условия:

```
a && b ? "A и B" : (a||b ? "A или B" : "NONE")
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function msg(a, b) {
  return a && b ? "A и B" : a || b ? "A или B" : "NONE";
};

for (let a = 0; a <= 1; a++) {
  for (let b = 0; b <= 1; b++) {
    console.log('a: ' + a + ', b: ' + b + ', msg: ' + msg(a, b));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно обычными if для понятности:

```js
function get (a, b) {
  if (a && b)
    return 'A и B'
  if (a || b)
    return 'A или B'

  return 'NONE'
}

console.log(get(false, true ))
console.log(get(true , true ))
console.log(get(false, false))
```